# reading the form data in servlet. data posted with post method and servlet called with ?q=test1

Tags: java, servlets, post

Hey I am trying to read the form data in a servlet sent with post method. And the servlet is called as `OnlineExam?q=saveQuestion`. Now the servlet is working as:

```
public class OnlineExam extends HttpServlet {
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
if(request.getParameter("q").equals("saveQuestion")){
                /*
                 * Save the question provided with the form as well as save the uploaded file if any.
                 */
                saveQuestion(request);
            }
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      doGet(request, response);
        saveQuestion(request);
    }
public String saveQuestion(HttpServletRequest request){         
        System.out.println(request.getParameter("question"));

        return "";

    }       
}
```

HTML form:

```
<form action="OnlineExam?q=saveQuestion" method="post">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Question</legend>
        <textarea class="questionArea" id="question" name="question">Enter Question.</textarea>
        <br class="clearFormatting"/>               
        <input class="optionsInput" value="optionA" name="optionA" onfocus = "clearValues('optionA')" onblur = "setValues('optionA')"/>
        <br class="clearFormatting"/>

        <input class="optionsInput" value="optionB" name="optionB" onfocus = "clearValues('optionB')" onblur = "setValues('optionB')"/>
        <br class="clearFormatting"/>

        <input class="optionsInput" value="optionC" name="optionC" onfocus = "clearValues('optionC')" onblur = "setValues('optionC')"/>
        <br class="clearFormatting"/>

        <input class="optionsInput" value="optionD" name="optionD" onfocus = "clearValues('optionD')" onblur = "setValues('optionD')"/>
        <br/>
        <input class="optionsInput" value="answer" name="answer" onfocus="clearValues('answer')" onblur="setValues('answer')"/>     
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        <input type="reset" value="Cancel" />
        <button style="display: none" onclick="return deleteQuestion()" >Delete</button>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
```

So can anyone illustrate how the servlet is actually called. I mean what is the flow of control i.e. how the things works in this servlet.

And how could i read the param1 there in servlet.

ps: i don't want to post form with get method.

Comment: Hey you all I need the way to read both get data which is q=savequestion and post data of form. So how to read the both and parse them?

Answer (score 6):

You should get the value of `q` in your `doPost` not in your `doGet`. Because you use `method="post"` then in the servlet the `doPost` is the one that called not the `doGet`. Remove the code in your `doGet` then insert it to `doPost`. And you `doPost` must be something like below code.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if(request.getParameter("q").equals("saveQuestion")){
        saveQuestion(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: HttpServletRequest.getAttribute("optionA") doesn't get form input downvote

Answer (score 4):

Is this solved ?

I am facing same problem.
I tried

```
Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
    System.out.println((String)paramNames.nextElement());
}
```

and it's showing 0 elements, so form data is not being read by servlet.

I got the answer in other thread.
`enctype=multipart/form-data` was causing this. After removing it from form, was able to read data.

Answer (score 3):

if you POST data to servlet.
`doPost` will get invoked.

Inside `doPost()` you can access request param like

```
request.getParameter("param1");
```

Comment: remove call of doGET from doPost , its of no use

Comment: as mentioned from doPost. just remove doGet's call from doPost

Comment: Hey i have removed the doGet call from doPost but it is still showing null

Comment: Hey jigar i have just done the changes to the question please review it. and thanks for being so nice :)

Comment: Hey i have added the actual source code with the question. please check out the edited question

Comment: just remove the param `q=saveQuestion` and pass it with hidden input

Answer (score 0):

When you click the "submit" button on your form, the doPost method of your servlet will be called - this is dictated by the method that you put on the "form" in your HTML page. The URL parameters ( q=saveQuestion ) will still be available to your code in the doPost method. You seem to be under the impression that the URL parameters will be processed by the doGet method and the form parameters by the doPost method. That is not the case.

Comment: But why i m not able to get the form fields of the form. Even though the doPost servlet is called.

Comment: Are you sure your doPost method is being called? Have you tried Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
    while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
      System.out.println((String)paramNames.nextElement()); } to see what parameters are reaching the servlet?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
doPost() {
  processRequest(request, response);
  //to do
}
```

Remove/comment `processRequest(request, response)` and try it again. Now you should not get null values.

Comment: @jvperrin, English is not my mother tongue. So very very disappointed with your down vote.

Comment: I did not down vote you, I only edited your post to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but could not find an answer to this when I searched so I am posting my solution for someone who may have the same issue with getting null from form parameters in the dopost function of their servlet.

I had a similar issue getting null values when using the request.getParameters("param1"); functions. After hours of playing around with it I realized that the param1 that I was using was the ID for the  input tag I was requesting. That was wrong. I had to use the NAME attribute of the input tag to get the correct value of the input box. That was all it was. I just had to add a name and get the parameter using this name and that fixed the issue.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I am new to java world and i have changed it to name but still i am getting null value :(

Comment: I'm using the name. still null

Answer (score -1):

Vinit try the below code
 `request.getParameter("param1");`

Comment: Hey actually i am trying the same as you written. that was just a typing mistake. see the edited question. And thanks for response

Comment: can you try removing ?q=saveQuestion #(just a suggestion not tried).Instead of appending in form action give argument "q" as hidden field in form

Comment: No i can't have that actually servlet is also doing some other work depending on the get parameters

Comment: @PhilipRego, Read my answer once again- it is getParameter not getAttribute. Reverse the down vote .look like you downvoted few other answers also. check those too.